# How to test that an error was raised inside of a flatMap function?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, try-catch, throw

Writing a unit test to make sure that an error is raised when some type property does not match a case in a switch statement. The throw is inside of a function that performs a chain of flatMaps and ends with a subscribe.

The try/catch does not end up catching anything raised from the called function, although the right error is raised by it that I see when I add an on error callback to the end of subscribe.

Currently I have it using the try/catch block to catch the throw, however I have also tried using the `expect(() => {}).toThrow()` chain with no success.

I have also tried using `throwError()` instead of `throw new Error()`

```js
it('should handle unknown list creation', async(() => {
    let service = new BlaService(...);

    let ids = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    let listType = 'dfklsjfdkls';

    try {
      service.handleCreateList(Observable.of({ ids: ids, listType: listType }));
      expect(true).toBe('expected exception to be thrown');
    } catch (ex) {
      expect(ex).toBe(listType + ' is not a recognized list type');
    }

    // expect( function () {
    //   service.handleCreateList(Observable.of({ ids: ids, listType: listType }));
    // }
    //   ).toThrow(new Error(listType + ' is not a recognized list type'));
  }));


public handleCreateList(contextObservable: Observable<any>): void {
        // a bunch of lets here

        contextObservable.flatMap((context) => {
            ids = context.ids;
            switch (context.listType) {
                case 'constituent':
                    idsetType = 0;
                    break;
                case ...
                    break;
                default:
                    // this is the throw we are testing
                    throw new Error(context.listType + ' is not a recognized list type');
            }
            return this.resources.getString(context.listType + '_list_name');
        }).flatMap((title: string) => {
            ...
            return url;
        }).flatMap((url: string) => {
            ...
            return requestResponse;
        }).flatMap((response) => {
            ... // generate a list of observables
            return forkJoin(observables);
        }).subscribe(() => {
            ...
          // does some navigation stuff here
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by subscribing to the output of `of()` used as input and use its error callback. Also the actual function needed to return and instead of a subscribe it needs to pipe and tap.